# Does changing code of callback cused by its execution affects those calls which are already queued?

Tags: javascript

What im asking is, if i got events a and b which both call function x upon completion, if both these events fire at same time, but a completes before b, causing change of value of variable z inside function x, will this affect callback tied event b, so it will fire with new value of z, or it will fire "old" version of z ?

Comment: there is no such thing as "the same time". it also depends how you implemented the access to the variable. if it's closured , it will not affect. but if you didnt and the latter function read the value again , it will see the new value

Comment: i could just write a program to test it but, perhas this depends of what events were speaking about so iw as hoping to get complex answer here from someone who already knows the answer.

Comment: It also depends on what you mean by "value of variable `z` inside function `x`"; is it in the closure of the `x` function? Otherwise functions do not retain the values of their local variables between calls. In any case, posting actual code would help greatly.

Comment: This is just a theoretical question, and i was thinking about very simple situation like function x() {var z = 0; ++z;} Mostly im interested if queued callback calls just store reference, or entire code of function at the time when this call was added to queue

Comment: In your simple situation, the `z` variable will not keep its value between calls. On each call to `x`, it will be initialized to 0 again. It would not matter if `x` is called as an event handler or directly, it will still not retain its value.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/nWkWV/1/ for an example.

Comment: Ok thanks, one more thing if something would modify function body while call from b is still in queue would that affect it ?

Comment: How would you modify the function _body_? If that _were_ possible, the second call to the function would have seen the modified body. When you register a function as an event handler, the function isn't "copied" in a list of event handlers, but only a reference to it is stored.

Comment: well i could just assign different value to function x if it was an expression like x = function() { do something } and then just overwrite it it with new line x = function() { do something else }

Comment: You're not modifying the function _body_ that way. The old function still remains (and is still assigned as an event listener), you're just changing the _value_ of the _variable_ `x` to a completely new function. The old function will still be called for handling events, not only for those in queue, but for any future events as well. Yes, function names are variables like any other, and functions themselves are values like any other.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/cFvu2/ for an example on function body modification.

Comment: sorry i didnt expressed myself clear enough. so if i understand correctly, if i overwrite function code in such way after it was registered as callback it would still fire an old version ?

Comment: @lanzz: Actually it is "copied" when the event is assigned. If you set an event and then change the function body the event still executes the "old" function.

Comment: Yes. When you register an event handler, a reference to the _function_ is registered (i.e. a reference to the _value_ of the _variable_ `x`). If you then change the _value_ of the _variable_ `x`, this does not affect the registered event handler, because it does not care or know anything about the _variable_ `x`.

Comment: Thanks, thats everything i wanted to know.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen It is not "copied". A reference to the _value_ of the function is registered as an event handler, not a _copy_ of it. Just like `function x() {}; var y = x;` does _not_ make a "copy" of the function, but just creates a new reference to the _same_ object (the function).

Comment: @SaniHuttunen [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5X3Gy/) — modifying attributes on one reference affects all references to the same object, because they're not _copies_ but just references.

Comment: @lanzz: Yes. A reference to the function is exactly what is stored in the event. (That's what I refered to as "copied", which I got from you comment). If you change the function variable you get a new reference but the event still has a "copy" of the old reference. We're on the same page here. :)

Comment: @SaniHuttunen You're helping spread a misconception. Inexperienced developers will think the wrong concept when they read your claims that functions are "copied". They're not. Using correct terminology matters.

Comment: You need to provide a code example here because the answer to your question is that it depends upon the code.  If the variable in question is in a closure, then each invocation of the async operation will have it's own separate copy of the closure and thus its own variables.  But, if the variable is global or is simply a reference to the same object, then changing it one place can affect the other place.  So, it depends upon the exact code.  Your question can't be answered in the abstract.  It has to be answered in the context of a specific variable in a specific piece of code.

Comment: Yes, after iv refreshed my knowledge regarding js functions iv realized how ambiguous my question was, but after reading all the answers and experimenting with provided code examples i think i got clear view on this matter now.